# If I create a Google+ Business page will my organic rank be effected in non-local areas?

Tags: local-seo, google-local-search

My website has two location landing pages - currently targeting two neighbouring towns that are outside of my actual place of business. Those respective pages rank within the top 3 organic listings of those relevant searches "{keyword} in {location}".

I am quite keen to add a Google+ Business page so I can have reviews and increase my perceived legitimacy. But I am concerned that if I add myself to Google+ Business that I might drop organic rank in the neighbouring out of town SERPs. I presume I will be added to the local cluster for my actual location - which isn't actually that important to me.

Does anyone have recent experience of adding or removing a business from Google+ Business and its resultant effect on organic rankings?

Comment: It won't harm it at all, deep url's remain in the organics. Only the front page will become localized, but even then it can rank in neighbouring towns with good SEO. Also, you want a good range of reviews from several platforms, not just Google Local.

Comment: What do you mean by "deep urls"?

The front page is used to target my actual location town and county - would I need to now use local SEO ranking factors like distance from center point, NAP and citations to make the homepage rank properly instead of non-local factors?

Comment: Your front page will become ranked for your town, and maybe neighbouring towns if your business is close enough, and assuming you have good local SEO (citations, reviews etc.) Pages that are not the front page are consider deep page/links, these will rank organic.

Comment: Okay well thanks for your input Simon. I am still sceptical; I think I'll stick with if it ain't broke attitude.

Comment: Well, without being added to Google Business your never rank in the top 3 for services, or products that are determined as a local search such "Web Design in Bournemouth and Plumber Bournemouth" etc, also... its possible to rank in all areas of the county by adding good authority and telling Google that you service all customers in a set radius, i.e 200 miles. Anyway, your choice.

Comment: Also, you should be aware that its possible for your site to be listed twice on the first page of results. I.e 1st position (local), and then 4th position (organic) on the same search, further increasing your click rates. Local doesn't replace organic, its an additional feature.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with 2 large companies in the same industry in Sydney and I can run SEO test between the 2 of them.

1. Once you are connected with local ip via a vps, you will see that the ranking is different in the location you are targeting. Google + will greatly affect it so you probably not even rank in the top 3 once you search with a local ip.
2. Your ranking will not be affected in other area, however other local businesses from this area may rank higher especially if you selling services.

Answer (score 0):

This is a totally cool question. The answer is as always in SEO "no one really knows what Google does" but in my view NO. But try using a good proxy to check. Make sure to use a NEW clean browser too. Set your proxy to say "Zurich Switzerland" and go to Google.ch in German and search.

Extra: IT MIGHT be helpful to your project to INCLUDE TARGET MARKET copy in your Google+ account. In other words say your target is English speaking Canada - then include (and use hash tags) press articles about recent news (related to your keywords) in major English speaking Canadian town.

Answer (score -1):

Google Search Rank isn't affected by Google+ pages, Business pages too
The Rank is affected by the website content

Comment: Do you have a reference or experience that supports your claim Google+ pages don't effect rankings?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Google Help pages themselves